# Selenium - to make find_elements. readable

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Basic concept I know:

`find_element` = find single elements. We can use `.text` or `get.attribute('href')` to make the element can be readable. Since `find_elements` is a list, we can't use  `.text`or `get.attribute('href')` otherwise it shows no attribute.

To scrape information to be readable from `find_elements`, we can use for loop function:

```
vegetables_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-brief-wrapper")

for i in vegetables_search:
    print(i.text)
```

Here is my problem, when I use `find_element`, it shows the same result. I searched the problem on the internet and the answer said that it's because using `find_element` would just show a single result only. Here is my code which hopes to grab different urls.

```
 links.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@rel='noopener']").get_attribute('href'))
```

But I don't know how to combine the results into pandas. If I print these codes, `links` variable prints the same url on the csv file...

```
vegetables_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-brief-wrapper")

Product_name =[]
links = []

for search in vegetables_search:
    Product_name.append(search.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text)
    links.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@rel='noopener']").get_attribute('href'))

#use panda modules to export the information
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': Product_name,'Link': links}) 
    df.to_csv('name.csv', index=False)
    print(df)
```

Certainly, if I use loop function particularly, it shows different links.(That's mean my Xpath is correct(!?))

```
product_link = (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@rel='noopener']"))
for i in product_link:
 print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

My questions:

1. Besides using for loop function, how to make `find_elements` becomes readable? Just like `find_element(By.attribute, 'content').text`
2. How to go further step for my code? I cannot print out different urls.
   Thanks so much. ORZ

This is the html code which's inspected from the website:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```py
links.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@rel='noopener']").get_attribute('href'))
```

should be changed to be

```py
links.append(search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@rel='noopener']").get_attribute('href'))
```

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@rel='noopener']").get_attribute('href')` will always search for the **first** element on the DOM matching `.//a[@rel='noopener']` XPath locator while you want to find the match **inside** another element.
To do so you need to change `WebDriver` `driver` object with `WebElement` `search` object you want to search inside, as shown above.